# JAVASCRIPT XMLHttpRequest() issue with Access Control Allow Origin

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

```
 var xhrReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrReq.withCredentials = true;
xhrReq.open("GET", "https://lootpaliveapi.snapfulfil.net/api", true, "******", "*******");
xhrReq.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
xhrReq.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://lootpaliveapi.snapfulfil.net");

xhrReq.onload = function(){
    console.log("READY STATE", xhrReq.readyState);
    if(this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("jsonDat").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
}

// Send Request to Get Data
xhrReq.send();
```

I have been trying to access third-party application server but Receiving some errors like above-mentioned one.

I would like to implement through javascript using XMLHttpRequest not from Server side because I'm my concern doesn't accept server-side scripts so.

Comment: The access control headers must be set by the *server*, not the client.

Comment: That is the job of the server side code. Allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin to all or specific domains in your server side code.

Comment: can I request through javascript using XMLHttpRequest API

Comment: @Harish — Read the duplicate question. In particular, the very first bullet point in the summary of the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to configure server side RestFull API to allow cross-origin requests.

OR

You can try to use an open source libraries to by pass CORS issue. Those libraries include: [Any Origin](http://anyorigin.com/), [Whatever Origin](http://www.whateverorigin.org/), [All Origins](http://multiverso.me/AllOrigins/), [crossorigin](https://crossorigin.me/)

Comment: Please give some more explanation whoever has down voted my answer.